# How to merge Spotify Accounts into Spotify Family?

Tags: spotify

I have Spotify Premium. My daughter also does, which is paid for by my wife's mobile phone contract. My son also uses Spotify for free, with ads.

I would like to merge all of these into the Spotify Family account, so that we are only paying once and all enjoying the same ad-free experience.

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: Ah, 10K views. Thanks WebApps stack exchange for the solitary upvote!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can only be done via the Spotify website, not the app.

1. Upgrade your Spotify Account to 'Family'
2. Use the Invite function to invite family members (they must live at your address), including those who **already** have Spotify accounts
3. They will be sent a link
4. The upgrade takes place seamlessly
5. Billing for their separate accounts automatically stops